# How to create a Web app using Juypter Notebook?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I want to build a web app. So I want the user to upload the file from the drop-down list select what process needs to be done on the file after the process is done it should give them an option to download.

This is the code which would be executed when they select the option from the drop-down list

```
df = pd.read_csv('STM158027061.csv',header=0,encoding = 'unicode_escape')
i=df['Policy Number'].count()
i=i-1
Advisor=df['Policy Number'].iloc[0]
a=0
for x in range(0,i):

    y=df['Policy Number'].ilox[x]
    if y == "Subagent Total":
        Advisor=df['Policy Number'].iloc[x+1]

    else:
        df['Advisor'].ilox[x]=Advisor
df = df.dropna(subset=['Advisor'])
df.to_csv('bt.csv')
```

In the same way, I have about 45 codes that should come up in the drop-down list.

Comment: Post your code as plain text, not an image.

Comment: Firstly, you can use Flask to create a lightweight python web application and while you are at it, you can add modules to execute the code above and more. You will have to add some HTML obviously though in order to create the drop-down and download buttons though.

Comment: @AnshumanTiwari is there any article to see sample code for it?